# How to efficiently apply PCA followed by SVD to extract the components of PCA?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, image-processing, matlab, segmentation

I am working on segmenting a textured image using Gabor Filters. This is based on this [paper](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~sfchang/course/dip/handout/jain-texture.pdf). There exist a Matlab [implementation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/texture-segmentation-using-gabor-filters.html) of this as well. Earlier I managed to do up to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172415/how-to-segment-a-textured-image-using-gabor-filters). With the help of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172470/how-to-resize-an-array-using-principal-component-analysis/172478#172478) now I come up with the following:

(* Design an array of Gabor Filters *)

```
{numRows, numCols} = ImageDimensions[img];

wavelengthMin = 4/Sqrt[2];
wavelengthMax = Sqrt[nrows^2 + ncols^2];
n = Floor[Log2[wavelengthMax/wavelengthMin]];
wavelength = Table[{2, 2} 2^i, {i, 0, n - 2}];
deltaTheta = Pi/4;
orientation = Table[i, {i, 0, Pi - deltaTheta, deltaTheta}];

gabormag = 
  Flatten[Table[
    ImageAdjust[
     GaborFilter[img, 1, wavelength[[i]], orientation[[j]]]], {i, 1, 
     Length@wavelength}, {j, 1, Length@orientation}]];
gaborWavelength = 
  Flatten[ConstantArray[
    Table[Norm[wavelength[[i]]], {i, 1, Length@wavelength}], 
    Length@orientation]];
```

(* Post-processing of Gabor Magnitude images into Gabor Features *)

```
K = 3;
gabormagfiltered = gabormag;
Table[
  sigma = 0.5 gaborWavelength[[i]];
  gabormagfiltered[[i]] = 
   ImageData[GaussianFilter[gabormag[[i]], K sigma]]
  , {i, 1, Length@gabormag}];
```

(* Add a map of spatial location information *)

```
meshgrid[x_List, y_List] := {ConstantArray[x, Length[y]], 
  Transpose@ConstantArray[y, Length[x]]}

{X, Y} = meshgrid[Range[ncols], Range[nrows]];
featureset = Append[Append[gabormagfiltered, X], Y];
```

(* Reshape Data *)

```
npoints = nrows*ncols;
freq = Dimensions[featureset][[1]];

Needs["Developer`"]
X = Developer`ToPackedArray[
   ArrayReshape[featureset, {freq, npoints}]];
```

(* Normalize the features to be zero mean, unit variance *)

```
Xstandardized = Standardize[X];
```

(* The following is based on the answer provided by @Michael E2 [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172470/how-to-resize-an-array-using-principal-component-analysis/172478#172478)*)
(* Apply Principal Component Analysis *)

```
pca = PrincipalComponents[Xstandardized];
X1 = Transpose[Transpose@Xstandardized - Mean[Xstandardized]];
```

(* Extract coefficients *)

```
{u, \[Sigma], v} = SingularValueDecomposition[X1];
```

However, when I apply `SingularValueDecomposition` on `X1` my machine (intel core i7, 16 GB RAM) runs out of memory, while in Matlab it works absolutely fine.

How can I efficiently apply PCA and SVD to extract the coefficients that I get directly using `pca` in Matlab?

For example, below are the original image, feature2DImage and clustered image (with 5 clusters)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you don't need all of them, try `{u, \[Sigma], v} = SingularValueDecomposition[X1, Length@SingularValueList[X1]];`

Comment: @MichaelE2 After getting `v` following your approach, I applied `feature2DImage = ImageAdjust@ImageResize[Image[X1.v], {225, 225}]`. However, this does not give the desired image. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Probably `Dimensions[v] = {50625, 21}` is a problem.

Comment: I think what you want is `PadRight[u.\[Sigma], {Automatic, Length@v}]`, since for the full SVD, `u.\[Sigma] == X1.v`.  But it still doesn't look like the right image.  If you have MATLAB, you might check the intermediate results.  Somehow I doubt `X1` is supposed to have a dimension `50625` if it's used to reconstruct the image as shown. -- Note `Standardize` zeros the mean, so `Transpose[Transpose@Xstandardized - Mean[Xstandardized]]` is unnecessary.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The dimension of `X1` is `{22, 50625}`. The dimension of `coeff` in Matlab is `22 X 22` while the dimension of `v` is `{50625, 21}` probably because `Length@SingularValueList[X1] = 21`

Comment: Try `SingularValueDecomposition[X1, Min@Dimensions@X1]` and `u.\[Sigma]` for `coeff`, then.  -- It would help if there were an example image that everybody could do the same computations as each other.  I don't think the web image of the puppy is exactly the same, or maybe you're using a different image.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have added the images.

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of your previous question [How to segment a textured image using Gabor Filters?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172415/how-to-segment-a-textured-image-using-gabor-filters)? I'm also pretty sure you posted another question based on the similar image, but I can't find it, maybe it has been deleted.

Comment: @anderstood They are related but not the same. In the earlier question, I asked for a complete answer and here (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172470/how-to-resize-an-array-using-principal-component-analysis/172478#172478) I asked to solve an implementational issue. Following that answer, I am getting another implementational issue which led me to this question.

Comment: Your last image show you made significant progress on texture segmentation, compared to few months ago! I remember I had worked on it without much success.

Comment: @anderstood Thanks a lot. But it is all there in matlab. I have just used the code for another textured image and struggling to replicate it in Mathematica.